How to write integration test for SignalR
I use Signalr in my Web API. How to perform integration testing on it? I do not want to mock Hub I want to work on real instance of connection and check the results.
Currently I have something like this. I can not establish connection to my hub
[Fact]
 public async Task Should_CreateUser()
 {
     using var client = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().CreateClient();

     var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
     handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
     var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
         .WithUrl(client.BaseAddress + "/auction-hub", options =>
         {
             options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => handler;
         })
         .Build();

     await connection.StartAsync();

 }

Hub:
namespace Bidnest.Application.Hubs
{
    public class AuctionHub : Hub<IAuctionHub>
    {

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Clients.All.UserWasOutbid($"Hey {Context.UserIdentifier}");
        }
    }
}


var handler = new HttpClientHandler(); <-- This won't work because you need to use the HttpClient returned from CreateClient because it doesn't actually go through the TCP/IP stack. Because no TLS connection is actually being made, the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback  won't ever be invoked.

My solution:
public class UserEventsTest : BaseIntegrationTest
{
    private readonly IntegrationTestWebAppFactory _factory;

    public UserEventsTest(IntegrationTestWebAppFactory factory) : base(factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_CreateUser()
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();
        var server = _factory.Server;
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/WeatherForecast");
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("wss://localhost" + "/auction-hub", options =>
            {
                options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => server.CreateHandler();
            })
            .Build();

        await connection.StartAsync();

    }
}

This line use IntegrationTestWebAppFactory
var client = _factory.CreateClient();

which is an abstraction of
new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().CreateClient()

So if you do not need abstraction you can go with this approach.
It creates application and expose endpoints.
Here I make sure standard HTTP requests are fine
var result = await client.GetAsync("/WeatherForecast");
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

And here I connect to my hub mapped in Program.cs
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("wss://localhost" + "/auction-hub", options =>
            {
                options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => server.CreateHandler();
            })
            .Build();

        await connection.StartAsync();


WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient() uses this:
        public HttpClient CreateClient() =>
            CreateClient(ClientOptions);

and ClientOptions is like this:
        public WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions ClientOptions { get; private set; } = new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions();

The constructor is empty, but the property has default value:
        public WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions()
        {
        }
// ...
        public Uri BaseAddress { get; set; } = new Uri("http://localhost");

So we can test with that default value like this:
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost")
            };
            Console.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress);

This outputs http://localhost/. Meaning, in your original post,
.WithUrl(client.BaseAddress + "/auction-hub",...

results in http://localhost//auction-hub that has double slash.
You can test it with:
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost")
            };
            Console.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress + "/auction-hub");

this results in http://localhost//auction-hub. So your address wasn't correct, and in your later self-answer, you changed it into more hard-coded "ws://localhost" + "/auction-hub", silently fixed the issue.

I appreciate your answer but there were more mistakes than doubled slash.
